# APPaymentEntry - Create Payment by entering values directly

Tags: acumatica

In the Payments Entry, I want to be able to create Payments directly, without having to link to an AP BIll or Credit Adjustment. Would it be possible to enter the payment directly by selecting the Supplier and entering the amounts accordingly? I also need the Print Checks functionality to work once I create the Payment in this approach. It seems that this is not possible out-of-the box but it is possible through a customization?

Comment: Why do you need this? What is the business case for this?

Comment: Basically performance. We need to clear a very large number and it would help if we don't have to create AP Bills.

Comment: Can you use Quick Checks for that purpose?

Comment: Sorry.. Not sure what Quick Checks is but I will check on it

Comment: Quick Checks is a form(AP304000) that represents both Check and Bill part of document entered through one interface. Here is quote from documentation: On this form, you can create a quick check to record a purchase that is immediately paid for by cash.